# find extension from string codeigniter asset loader

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a model in codeigniter in which I basically want to be able to input a file or array of files into the function and then render the proper html for that file. I am using `strchr` to find the last occurrence of the `.` and then get everything after. However this is not working as I figured it would according to php documentation (the function always returns false).

Here is the model:

```
<?php

class Asset_Load_Model extends CI_Model {

    public static $jsWrapperStart = '<script type="text/javascript" src="';
    public static $jsWrapperEnd = '"></script>';
    public static $cssWrapperStart = '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="';
    public static $cssWrapperEnd = '">';
    public static $imageTypes = array ( 'gif', 'jpeg', 'png', 'swf', 'psd', 'bmp', 'tiff', 'tiff', 'jpc', 'jp2', 'jpf', 'jb2', 'swc', 'aiff', 'wbmp', 'xbm');

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');
    }
    /**
     * Load an asset based on extension in string
     *
     * @param string/array $file
     * @param string $class for image types only
     */
    public function loadAsset($file, $class = '') {
        $out = '';
        if(is_array($file)) {
            $files = array();
            foreach ($files as $file) {
                $out .= $this->loadAsset($file);
            }
            return $out;
        } else {
            $ext = strrchr($file, '.');
            if ($ext == 'css') {
                return self::cssWrapperStart . base_url() . $file . self::cssWrapperEnd;
            } elseif ($ext == 'js') {
                return self::jsWrapperStart . base_url() . $file . self::jsWrapperEnd;
            } elseif (in_array($ext, self::$imageTypes)) {
                $class = isset($class) ? ' class="' . $class . '"' : '';
                return '<img alt="" src="' . base_url() . $file . '"' . $class . '>';
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Sample usage:

```
$dataFooter['page_level_plugins'] = $this->asset_load_model->loadAsset(array('assets/plugins/bootstrap-modal/js/bootstrap-modal.js', 'assets/plugins/bootstrap-modal/js/bootstrap-modalmanager.js', 'assets/plugins/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js', 'assets/plugins/select2/select2.min.js'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$files = array();
foreach ($files as $file) {
    $out .= $this->loadAsset($file);
}
```

You are declaring `$files` as an empty array before the `foreach` and as such aren't sending anything to `loadAssets`.

Try something like

```
foreach ($file as $f) {
    $out .= $this->loadAsset($f);
}
```

Comment: made the change. still isnt working. although it is iterating through the array properly. but still returning false. i am convinced it is something to do with the way im getting the .js or .css

Comment: Oh right. Yeah, `strrchr` will return something like `.css` (with the period). So you need to check for it thusly `$ext == '.css'` or strip out the period.

Comment: its returning .css i got it now

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

class Asset_Load_Model extends CI_Model {

    public static $jsWrapperStart = '<script type="text/javascript" src="';
    public static $jsWrapperEnd = '"></script>';
    public static $cssWrapperStart = '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="';
    public static $cssWrapperEnd = '">';
    public static $imageTypes = array ( 'gif', 'jpeg', 'png', 'swf', 'psd', 'bmp', 'tiff', 'tiff', 'jpc', 'jp2', 'jpf', 'jb2', 'swc', 'aiff', 'wbmp', 'xbm');

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');
    }
    /**
     * Load an asset based on extension in string
     *
     * @param string/array $file
     * @param string $class for image types only
     */
    public function loadAsset($file, $class = '') {
        $out = '';
        if(is_array($file)) {
            foreach ($file as $f) {
                $out .= $this->loadAsset($f);
            }
            return $out;
        } else {
            $ext = substr(strrchr($file, '.'), 1);
            if ($ext == 'css') {
                return self::$cssWrapperStart . base_url() . $file . self::$cssWrapperEnd;
            } elseif ($ext == 'js') {
                return self::$jsWrapperStart . base_url() . $file . self::$jsWrapperEnd;
            } elseif (in_array($ext, self::$imageTypes)) {
                $class = isset($class) ? ' class="' . $class . '"' : '';
                return '<img alt="" src="' . base_url() . $file . '"' . $class . '>';
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}

?>
```